# Передача данных из одного окна в другое несколько раз MVVM WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть окно, на котором располагаются 2 кнопки, по нажатию на кнопку вылезает новое окошко со списком и кнопкой "Применить". Я выбираю нужный пункт в списке и нажимаю применить. По нажатию на вторую кнопку, вылезает то же окошко, но я выбираю другой пункт и жму применить.
Вопрос: Как передать разные значения, чтобы они сохранялись для каждой кнопки?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: если у вас вопрос по коду, то приведите код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные (что нажато, какие параметры и прочее) Вы, полагаю, храните в каком-то классе.
Пусть каждая кнопка обращается к своему экземпляру класса.